# How to fetch only contents excluding brackets using sql query?

Tags: sql, snowflake-schema

In the database, I have column name RESOLUTIONID where data looks like the following content.

```
[ 20893016 ]
[ 20893020 ]
[ 20893013 ]
```

I want to fetch only the contents like the below ones.

```
20893016
20893020
20893013
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your column is actually array content, with just a single element in it.  You may use `ARRAY_SLICE` here to select that single element:

```
SELECT
    ARRAY_SLICE(col, 0, 1) AS num
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Yes, it is array content, but it will always have only one element. I do not want brackets to be visible when I download in csv. Please help me to remove brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GET()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get.html):

```
select get(RESOLUTIONID, 1) as RESOLUTIONID
```